# Angular 2 PercentPipe unusual output

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

The following bindings:

```
{{ -50.52338914680037 }}
{{ -50.52338914680037 | number }}
{{ -50.52338914680037 | percent }}
```

Produce:

```
-50.52338914680037
-50.523
-5,052.339%
```

I would anticipate the output of the percent pipe to be

```
-50.523%
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get your anticipated result of `-50.523%` use this code:

```
{{ (-50.52338914680037 / 100) | percent }}
```

or

```
{{ -0.5052338914680037 | percent:'2.0-3' }}
```

Have a look at the `DecimalPipe` ([API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-pipe.html)) for format adjustments if needed.

Comment: Well that's the default format anyway yeah? At any rate, even with it specified it, I get the same result: -5, 052.339%.

Comment: Oh geez...Yep sorry, can't believe I've missed that.